# Python Suddenly Not Recognising imports

Tags: windows, python

I've been working on a script for several months and it has been run at least 50 times. Yesterday I open up VS Code and try to run it as normal and get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 5, in 
    import Preprocessing as p
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Documents\University\Academics\Postgraduate\Honours\Project\honoursProject\Preprocessing.py", line 2, in 
    import plotly.plotly as py
ImportError: No module named 'plotly'

The terminal no longer recognises any of my imports. I tried to run another python script with different imports and get the same error (just with that module name).

What I have tried:
Running pip list to check if the modules are installed - They are,
Upgrading pip installer,
Repairing python through the python installer,
Modifying python components through the python installer,
Running the scripts through cmd instead of VS Code terminal.

None of the things I've tried resolves the issue, please help. The version of python is 3.7.3 and I'm using Windows 10 and all modules are installed/downloaded using pip

Comment: So the issue was that I had installed a program that was dependent on an older version of python and then that had written over the path files and caused clashes in the directory. To solve I had to uninstall the current version and upgrade to the newest version of python

Comment: Since this solution worked for you, you may want to consider writing a more detailed step-by-step answer and answer your own question.